# Add string after index entry and page pointers without intervening comma

Tags: indexing

In my thesis there are a large number of Arabic terms. I include these (transcribed) in the index. I would like to add the corresponding English term in parenthesis after the index entry, before the pointers to pages. To do this I define the command `\trans` that works in a similar way to the `\see` and `\seealso` commands. I put these command at the start of the document to ensure that they come before the page pointers in the index. This works fine, but the problem is that it produces a comma between the Arabic term and the translation, like so:

> arabic term, (english translation), 2, 3

Is there a way to get rid of this comma for entries for which there are a translations? The output I want is

> arabic term (english translation), 2, 3

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{
\index{arabic term|trans{english translation}}
}

\newcommand\trans[2]{(#1)}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\clearpage\kant[2]
\index{arabic term} 
\clearpage
\kant[3]
\index{arabic term} 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `andreas.ist` (or whatever name you prefer, so long as the extension is `.ist`) in the same directory as your main TeX file, with the following contents

```
delim_0 "\\addindexcomma"
```

Now change your document to read

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1,options=-s andreas.ist]
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \index{arabic term|trans{english translation}}%
}

\newcommand\trans[2]{(#1)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addindexcomma}{%
  \@ifnextchar\trans{\space}{,\space}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\clearpage\kant[2]
\index{arabic term} 
\clearpage
\kant[3]
\index{arabic term} 

\index{bar} % for testing

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run the MWE it works fine, but when I implement it on my actual thesis the `\index` commands with the `trans` produce duplicate entries in the index, with the comma.

Comment: @Andreas My crystal ball says nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. I'll investigate further.

Comment: @Andreas Are you perhaps hiding `\index` in some macro?

Comment: No, but I am using macros in them.

Comment: @Andreas Without an example that goes wrong…

Comment: Right, it'll take a while to produce though. I'll be back.